# enableServiceLinks=false doesn't disable Kubernetes clusterIP default service environment variables to be injected into pod

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

In pod specification, there is the option `enableServiceLinks`. When set to false, environment variables related to services running at the moment of pod creation will not be injected into pod.

The problem is that I expected this to also happen with kubernetes clusterIp service on default namespace:

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.116.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    27d
```

But it is injecting environment variables into pod as follows:

```
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.116.0.1:443
NODE_VERSION=12.18.0
HOSTNAME=static-web
YARN_VERSION=1.22.4
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
test_value=8585
TERM=xterm
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.116.0.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.116.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.116.0.1
PWD=/indecision-app
```

Deployment file used for deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: indecision-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: indecision-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: indecision-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: indecision-app
    spec:
      enableServiceLinks: false
      containers:
      - name: indecision-app
        image: hleal18/indecision-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Is this the correct behavior? Is there an API-supported way of avoiding these service environment variables to be injected?

Comment: kubernetes version?

Comment: Client 1.18 - Server 1.15

Comment: Sorry, in case it wasn't clear, I'm specifically talking about avoiding kubernetes service env vars. Other services are not being injected.

Comment: @hleal18 Does [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9050c510e640f325d008792a517fe85808b34150/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L523) answer your question? `We always want to add environment variabled for master services from the master service namespace, even if enableServiceLinks is false.`

Comment: Yep, thank you very much, it provides more clarity. Looks like we can't get rid of it or at least, not advisable to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9050c510e640f325d008792a517fe85808b34150/pkg/kubelet/kubelet_pods.go#L523):

> We always want to add environment variabled for master services from
> the master service namespace, even if `enableServiceLinks` is false.

Which basically means that you will and should not prevent those specific environment variables from being injected to the pods.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: But what if I want to? For additional isolation.

Comment: @felipecrs NOTE that the injection only occurs in the default namespace: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/e8366c8e99791045a9c8fb2cd2bb46a8ea53d500